# Notepad++ expand/collapse code blocks for the user defined languages

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, notepad++, tal, udl2

I am trying to add the syntax plugin for the TAL (Transaction Application Language) in Notepad++

I have downloaded the xml file for TAL from http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Language_Files and kept in C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++ folder.

After the above step, I have restarted Notepad++ and I could see all the keywords are getting highlighted correctly but the expand/collapse of the blocks are not working as expected.

The downloaded xml file has the following lines for the code expand/collapse.

```
    <Keywords name="Folders in code1, open">BEGIN ?nolist</Keywords>
    <Keywords name="Folders in code1, middle"></Keywords>
    <Keywords name="Folders in code1, close">END; ?list</Keywords>
```

As per the above xml statement the block ends at END; (Semicolon)

The syntax for the conditional statements will be as below,

```
IF CONDITION1 THEN
   BEGIN
     statements;
   END;

IF CONDITION2 THEN
   BEGIN
     statements;
   END  -- no semicolon
ELSE IF CONDITION3 THEN
   BEGIN
      statements;
   END;
```

The expand/collapse is working good for the first syntax example. In the second syntax the first BEGIN ending at END;(semicolon) where as it should end at END (No semicolon)

I have modified the third line to

```
<Keywords name="Folders in code1, close">END ?list</Keywords>
```

and I started seeing the block ending at the partial words as below.

```
IF CONDITION4 THEN
   BEGIN
     statements;
     SENDTOSERVER();  -- ending here as END is present
     statements;
END;
```

Changing the third line to any of below line also resulted the same.

```
<Keywords name="Folders in code1, close">END END; ?list</Keywords>
<Keywords name="Folders in code1, close">"END" "END;"?list</Keywords>
```

How can I match ending blocks to either END or END; (complete word).
I am using the notepad++ version 7.2.2

Comment: have you tried `Folding in code2 style`, it uses backward search. ([UDL help](http://udl20.weebly.com/folding-in-code.html)).

Comment: @Cricrazy Thanks for the help. It worked partially, expand/collapse working fine but the keywords BEGIN, END are not highlighted now with the suggestion.

Comment: Now the keywords are highlighted.Notepad++ -> Language -> Define you language and for my user language updated the foreground color in "Folding in code 2 style"